# How to move border-bottom further down?

Tags: html, css

How to move border-bottom `border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;` further down without specifying the height of `<li>` (`.content-intro-full-right ul li`)

In the `<li>` (`.content-intro-full-right ul li`) - it contain `<ul>` of operating systems.

For example:  http://jsfiddle.net/t6gB7/12/

You can see `border-bottom` should appear below of operating system list.

```
<div class="content-intro-full-right">    
<ul>   
  <li>
     <ul class="operating-system">
        <li>Fedora</li>
        <li>ArchLinux</li>
        <li>FreePBX</li>
      </ul>
     <ul class="operating-system" style="margin-right: 140px;">
       <li>CentOS</li>
       <li>Ubuanto</li>
       <li>Debian</li>
       <li>Gentoo</li>
       <li>Slackware</li>
     </ul>
     <h4>Operating Systems</h4>
     <p>
      We offer a variety of Linux operating systems.
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
​

.content-intro-full-right ul li {
    position: relative;
    padding: 30px 280px 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}

ul.operating-system  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 0;
}

ul.operating-system li, ul.operating-system li:nth-child(even) {
    border:none;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 80px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
    color:#808080;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

ul.operating-system li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can float the `ul`s to the right and add a div with `clear: both` to force the border down. I've demonstrated in this fiddle, although I messed up the spacing around the list of OSes and I left in some colored borders to show the boundaries of the elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/t6gB7/19/

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way without using `<div class="clear"></div>` ?

Comment: There may be, but I couldn't find one so quickly. But I'm not a CSS pro, so maybe there is. With your newly gained knowledge about using `float` instead of `position: absolute`, you may find better ways to implement it than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the padding-bottom (3rd value after `padding:`) to extend the box further down. But this is kinda hacky.

```
.content-intro-full-right ul li {
    position: relative;
    padding: 30px 280px 160px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}
```

### Edit: without absolute position http://jsfiddle.net/t6gB7/20/

```
<div class="container">
     <ul class="operating-system">
        <li>Fedora</li>
        <li>ArchLinux</li>
        <li>FreePBX</li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="operating-system">
       <li>CentOS</li>
       <li>Ubuanto</li>
       <li>Debian</li>
       <li>Gentoo</li>
       <li>Slackware</li>
     </ul>

     <h4>Operating Systems</h4>
     <p>
        We offer a variety of Linux operating systems.
     </p>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
​

.container {
    padding: 30px 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: right;
}

ul.operating-system  {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

ul.operating-system li, ul.operating-system li:nth-child(even) {
    border:none;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 80px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
    color:#808080;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

ul.operating-system li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm I don't want to do this because each <li>, the content can be more or less.

Comment: Well then you should not use absolute positions but rather `float: right;` and add a `clear: right;` at the bottom of your container.

Answer (score 0):

opatut is right , as long as you use "`position: absolute;`" you cant achieve this. 
Here is another sample done with float and clear ... btw upping opatuts answer

http://jsfiddle.net/t6gB7/21/